# How to write string with many characters [, > etc without writing it singly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a problem, because everytime i need to write indexof, i need to use +
for example:

```
String lsdfrom2 = '[' + '"' + "LSD" + ',' + '[' + ']' + ',' + '{' + '"' + "token" + '"' + ":" + '"';
```

How to write it in another way? thats soo anoying to write it like in example
I mean, how to read text below without write every char singly

```
["LSD",[],{"token":"
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Some thing wrong with this: `[\"LSD\",[],{\"token\":\"` ?

Comment: this would require you to understand the difference between `char and string` do some research / reading up on this in your spare time

Comment: Worth noting is that two single quotes is not the same as a double quote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write it as a string (escaping the quotes is required via `\"`)

```
String lsdfrom2 = "[\"LSD\",[],{\"token\":\""
```

Answer (score 2):

Write is as a string literal with " to escape the quotes.

```
string mystring = @"[""LSD"",[],{""token"":""";
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to escape the quotation marks?

```
string lsdfrom2 = "[\"LSD\",[],{\"token\":\"";
```

See: [Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotes

```
String lsdfrom2 = "[\"LSD\",[],{\"token\":\"" // escaping the quotes..
```